# How can i get index use forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to

```html
<ul class="product">
  <li>aaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbb</li>
  <li class="on">ccccc</li>
  <li>ddddd</li>
</ul>
```

```js
const product = document.querySelector(".product");
const productList = product.querySelectorAll("li");

function getIdx() {
  productList.forEach((list, idx) => {
    let productClassList = list.classList;
    let parsedList = Array.from(productClassList);

    if (parsedList.includes("on")) {
      return idx;
    }
  });
};

function printIdx() {
  let idx = getIdx();

  console.log(idx); // Print undefined
}

productList.forEach(list => {
  list.addEventListener("click", printIdx);
});
```

but it is not working, it is always print "undefined" when i click content of li tag

i wanna get index when i click content of li tag and i wanna use that like web shopping site

how can i get index?

Comment: `parsedList.includes("on")` - alwats returns false.

Comment: your return statement is for the `.forEach((list, idx) => { }`, not for the function `getIdx()`

Comment: IF you want to return the index, use a normal for loop: `for(let idx = 0; idx < productList.length; idx++) { ... }`

Comment: Also, do you want to get the index of `on` element or index of the clicked element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `for` loop and use `classList.contains()` to check if the class is present. Also, you need to declare a local var, to store the index returned from the loop.

```js
const product = document.querySelector(".product");
const productList = product.querySelectorAll("li");

function getIdx() {
  let idx;
  for (var i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
    let list = productList[i];

    if (list.classList.contains("on")) {
      idx = i;
    }
  }
  return idx;
};

function printIdx() {
  let idx = getIdx();

  console.log(idx);
}

productList.forEach(list => {
  list.addEventListener("click", printIdx);
});
```

```html
<ul class="product">
  <li>aaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbb</li>
  <li class="on">ccccc</li>
  <li>ddddd</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can i put "return" in if statement like "return idx = i;" if i wanna finish for loop quickly?

Comment: @Alpaca just add a `break` after `idx = i` line. It will cause to end the loop.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to save the index outside the foreach loop like this:

```js
const product = document.querySelector(".product");
const productList = product.querySelectorAll("li");

function getIdx() {
  //var for holding the correct index
  let index = -1;
  productList.forEach((list, idx) => {
    let productClassList = list.classList;
    let parsedList = Array.from(productClassList);

    if (parsedList.includes("on")) {
      //put the index we found and exit the loop
      index = idx;
      return;
    }
  });
  //return the value
  return index;
};

function printIdx() {
  let idx = getIdx();

  console.log(idx); // Print undefined
}

productList.forEach(list => {
  list.addEventListener("click", printIdx);
});
```

```html
<ul class="product">
  <li>aaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbb</li>
  <li class="on">ccccc</li>
  <li>ddddd</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't exit a forEach() call early

Answer (score 0):

Well, a safer way to get all `<li>`s with the class "on" you could do something like the following:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".product li")]
.reduce((a,li,i)=>{
  li.onclick=()=>console.log(a);
  li.classList.contains("on")&&a.push(i)
  return a
},[]);
```

```html
<ul class="product">
  <li class="one">this will not be selected</li> 
  <li>bbbbb</li>
  <li class="a on b">this will be selectd</li>
  <li class="on">and this one too!</li>
</ul>
```

Fun fact: in my `.reduce()` call I assemble the array `a` that will only exist in the scope of the callback function as I don't store the return value of the `.reduce()`-call. But within its scope `a` will be referenced in the event handler function for each `<li>`.